# e.preventDefault not stopping redirect on form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I realise this has been asked a myriad of times in the past - though I have looked through 4 or 5 of these threads and for the life of me I cannot figure out what is causing my form to redirect! Please help!

Here is my form submission function:
Every time I select an option from my  element, the form fires off and (successfully) posts to form.php, though it also redirects even though I've included event.preventDefault(); Can you spot anything that may be blocking this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#quote_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    select();
});

});

function select(){
    error(0);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form.php",
        data: $('#quote_form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#graph_var_1").html(data.message1);
            $("#graph_var_2").html(data.message2);
            $("#graph_var_3").html(data.message3);
            $("#graph_var_4").html(data.message4);
        }

    });

}


function result(act,txt)
{
    if(txt) $('#subcategory').html(txt);
}
</script>
```

EDIT: I was mucking around with it before posting (trying to get it to work) and must have missed the (e) (event) inconsistency - though I have changed it back and still no luck. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<form id="quote_form" name="quote_form" method="post" action="form.php">
                    <label>Quarterly Power Bill Value</label>
                    <select name="bill_value" id="bill_value" size='1' onChange='this.form.submit();'>
                        <option value="200">200</option>
                        <option value="250">250</option>
                        <option value="300">300</option>
                        <option value="350">350</option>
                        <option value="400">400</option>
                        <option value="450">450</option>
                        <option value="500">500</option>
                        <option value="550">550</option>
                        <option value="600">600</option>
                        <option value="650">650</option>
                        <option value="700">700</option>
                        <option value="750">750</option>
                        <option value="800">800</option>
                        <option value="850">850</option>
                        <option value="900">900</option>
                        <option value="950">950</option>
                        <option value="1000">1000</option>
                        <option value="1050">1050</option>
                        <option value="1100">1100</option>
                        <option value="1150">1150</option>
                        <option value="1200">1200</option>
                        <option value="1250">1250</option>
                        <option value="1300">1300</option>
                        <option value="1350">1350</option>
                        <option value="1400">1400</option>
                        <option value="1450">1450</option>
                        <option value="1500">1500</option>
                        <option value="1550">1550</option>
                        <option value="1600">1600</option>
                        <option value="1650">1650</option>
                        <option value="1700">1700</option>
                        <option value="1750">1750</option>
                        <option value="1800">1800</option>
                        <option value="1850">1850</option>
                        <option value="1900">1900</option>
                        <option value="1950">1950</option>
                        <option value="2000">2000</option>
                        <option value="2050">2050</option>
                        <option value="2100">2100</option>
                        <option value="2150">2150</option>
                        <option value="2200">2200</option>
                        <option value="2250">2250</option>
                        <option value="2300">2300</option>
                        <option value="2350">2350</option>
                        <option value="2400">2400</option>
                        <option value="2450">2450</option>
                        <option value="2500">2500</option>
                        <option value="2550">2550</option>
                        <option value="2600">2600</option>
                        <option value="2650">2650</option>
                        <option value="2700">2700</option>
                        <option value="2750">2750</option>
                        <option value="2800">2800</option>
                        <option value="2850">2850</option>
                        <option value="2900">2900</option>
                        <option value="2950">2950</option>
                        <option value="3000">3000</option>
                    </select><br />
                    <label>Approx Power Usage between 8am to 4pm</label>
                    <select name="peak_usage" id="peak_usage" size='1' onChange='this.form.submit();'>
                        <option value="10">10%</option>
                        <option value="20">20%</option>
                        <option value="30">30%</option>
                        <option value="40">40%</option>
                        <option value="50">50%</option>
                        <option value="60">60%</option>
                        <option value="70">70%</option>
                        <option value="80">80%</option>
                        <option value="90">90%</option>
                        <option value="100">100%</option>
                    </select><br />

                </form>
```

Console: only shows a couple of missing image errors, nothing else.

SOLUTION: Turns out this was being caused by the way my form was submitting. I replaced the OnClick calls with a submit button - and it worked.

Comment: Could you supply your form html code?

Comment: Weird how the existing answers and the question do not line up. I am guessing there was a stealth edit to the question.

Comment: Set preserve console on page navigation and see if there are errors in the console.

Comment: @epascarello yeah sorry I was trying to reply to the answers and they all came so fast - struggling to keep up haha.

Comment: Why are you calling submit and not just a function that does the Ajax call?

Comment: I'm new to AJAX and was following guides, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#quote_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    select();
});
```

instead of:

```
$('#quote_form').submit(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();//error event is undefinded
    select();
});
```

### Update

If you add `onlick="this.form.submit()"` its submitting form and firing jquery submit event. I found a solution:

remove `onclick` from select and add click event in `document.ready`, also remove `error(0)` its giving error `error not defined`.

```
$("#peak_usage").change(function(){
    $('#quote_form').submit();
});
```

You can also set:

```
<select name="peak_usage" id="peak_usage" size='1' onchange="$('#quote_form').submit();">
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> Reason: Because this.form will give you the form of the form element.
> and $('#quote_form') gives you form object.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RLRM8/1/)

Comment: Hey - Sorry I was attempting to change that before posting and in my mucking around I forgot to change it back. Even with consistent (e) usage it doesn't work. My apologies!

Comment: after the redirect, nope: http://puu.sh/alSjj/6eb3fa33e8.jpg

Though on the initial pageload I get a couple missing image errors. http://puu.sh/alSmu/8ff3d9d1c0.png

I didn't think that could be causing it :3 Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

here is the mistake, your parameter name is `e` while you are using `event` when calling `preventDefault()`:

```
 $('#quote_form').submit(function(e) {
-----> event.preventDefault();    ^
                                  |
                                  |
```

change it to match the parameter name:

```
 $('#quote_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

or:

```
 $('#quote_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

or another way:

```
 $('#quote_form').submit(function() {
        select();
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change that back before posting (I was experimenting with fixes and missed this). Even with consistent (e) usage the page still redirects. Anything else you see that may be getting in the way?

Comment: you can put return statement at end of event see edit

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sadly it still redirects even with the return false :\

Comment: its may be because you are submitting form as well programmatically

Comment: You got it. I removed the submits and coded a button to do it - fixed.

Comment: yes i was not sure but it is now sure that programmatically submit not fires the jquery submit event handler

Answer (score 1):

Either try to change the `event` to `e`

```
$('#quote_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    select();
}
```

Or change the button type of `quote_form` to `button` from `submit` and give click event on that like

```
$('#quote_form').click(function() {
    select();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have parameter variable `e` and using `event` inside function. So change parameter variable to `event` or make `e.preventDefault()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#quote_form').submit(function(event) {// (e) change to (event)
    event.preventDefault();
    select();
});
```

Comment: Hey - Sorry I was attempting to change that before posting and in my mucking around I forgot to change it back. Even with consistent (e) usage it doesn't work. My apologies!